# Is there any solution to continue the conference call on low bandwidth in vidyo.io library?

Tags: vidyo

I am developing an application using vidyo.io library and facing problem of connection on low bandwidth i.e. during conference call is disconnecting due to network issues or low internet issues. Please share any solution regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

In low bandwidth situation, the frame rate and resolution of video will be lowered accordingly. You can try muting the camera and use voice-only call (which needs about 150Kbps bandwidth).